# How do I determine the correct header files when building gcc from source files (libstdc++-v3 build)

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

I am new to building gcc from source files.  I am building a cross compiler version of this for QNX.

Part of the process is to modify build_hooks with the information about the version of QNX and some path information.

I am to the point in the process where libstdc++-v3 is being built.  The cross compiler is building fine and it is being used to build the libstdc++ sources.

It moves along fine until it starts inlcuding header files such as math.h.  Specifically it is building complex_io.c.  It is including cmath, which does a #include_next "math.h"

At this point a number of redefinition of function errors appear, for example:

```
In file included from /home/parallels/qnx-core-dev-tools/core-dev-tools/tools/gcc/branches/gcc_8_2_branch/linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/libstdc++-v3/include/complex:44,
                 from ../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/complex_io.cc:25:
/home/parallels/qnx-core-dev-tools/core-dev-tools/tools/gcc/branches/gcc_8_2_branch/linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:80:3: error: redefinition of 'double std::abs(double)'
   abs(double __x)
   ^~~
In file included from /home/parallels/qnx-core-dev-tools/core-dev-tools/tools/gcc/branches/gcc_8_2_branch/linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/libstdc++-v3/include/cmath:36,
                 from /home/parallels/qnx-core-dev-tools/core-dev-tools/tools/gcc/branches/gcc_8_2_branch/linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/libstdc++-v3/include/complex:44,
                 from ../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/complex_io.cc:25:
/opt/qnx660/target/qnx6/usr/include/math.h:720:15: note: 'double std::abs(double)' previously defined here
 inline double abs(double _Left) // OVERLOADS
               ^~~
```

The build of the cross compiler caused include search paths to the base install of QNX's (/opt/qnx660/target/qnx6/usr/include) header files, and thus when cmath does a #include_next "math.h", the math.h being included comes from this directory path.

What I am trying to understand is where is the correct math.h located in the source tree of libstdc++-v3?  There are several to choose from and I have been unsuccessful as of yet in picking the correct one.

```
./fixincludes/tests/base/ansi/math.h
./fixincludes/tests/base/architecture/ppc/math.h
./fixincludes/tests/base/math.h
./libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/math.h
./libstdc++-v3/include/c_compatibility/math.h
./linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/math.h
./linux-x86-o-ntox86/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0/pic/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/math.h
```

Even if I knew which one was correct, I also am not sure how to configure the build so that it choose the correct math.h without having to hack any of the auto-generated Makefiles.

Ideas?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: It's typically a header provided by your system libc, not the compiler.

Comment: @Shawn I was wondering about that.  I didn't know if the build of libstdc++-v3 was self contained in the code package for gcc (e.g. all files were present, including header files) or if there were some dependencies to the source package that were expected to be on the system doing the build.

Comment: gcc has a mailing list, where I would think someone will be more likely to find experienced gcc developers who might be able to offer some useful help.

Comment: Ah, good idea, I will do that, thank you @SamVarshavchik

Comment: I just compiled a cross compiler (avr-gcc) and at the begining I had some difficulties to. The problem was that I already had an older version of avr-gcc and the environment variables. I move the older version to a different location, and read very carefully the gcc documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html, and it compiled right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intention is that a C++ compiler can use the system `math.h` file provided by (or for use with) the C compiler.  However, it appears that `math.h` itself has some C++-style bits in the `std` namespace (based on the `// OVERLOADS` comment), and that confuses the libstdc++ implementation.

You need to look at what your copy of `math.h` defines.  Maybe there is a preprocessor option you can use to disable these C++ definitions.  Then you could set it before the `#include_next` directive.  Or since your `math.h` header is apparently C++-enabled already, it may be possible to delete the definitions of the `abs` and `modf` functions from `libstdc++-v3/include/c/cmath`.

Considering these problems, I would expect that more porting effort will be required, though.

Comment: Thanks Florian.  The cmath include file in the older qnx gcc (4.7.2 I think) is practically the same as the cmath in the 8.2 gcc version.  So there is something up with preprocessor directives that need to be sorted I think.

Comment: The 8.2 build of GCC as I downloaded it (it was modified for the QNX platform) was also missing header files from the libstdc++-v3/include/c folder.  When I updated that folder with the necessary header files, it built without a complaint.   Your clarification on how the build process works and generally what header files it used was very helpful in getting my thoughts oriented correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: The `libstdc++-v3/include/c` headers used by QNX have almost certainly bitrotted. I've made dozens of changes to the `libstdc++-v3/include/c_global` headers, without making the corresponding changes to the `c` ones (because I didn't know if anybody cared or still used them). Please report a bug so I can update the `c` ones: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/